# ember-data observe record array isLoading/isUpdating/hasUpdated?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to display an list of calendar events by week. The kicker is I am trying to reuse data already in the DS.Store. This is the code that does it and for the most part it works.

The problem is my `eventsChanged` observer is running way too many times. When the router fetches events from the server the `eventsChanged` observer fires for each record. I understand why that happens. What I don't get is why there is not a way to check if the recordArray is done loading a batch of records.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
App.CalendarWeekRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    Ember.Object.create
      date:  params.date
      login: params.login

  serialize: (model) ->
    date:  model.get 'date'
    login: model.get 'login'

  setupController: (controller, model) ->

    App.Event.find
      login: model.get 'login'
      week:  model.get 'date'

    events    = App.Event.all()
    days      = App.DaysOfWeekFor( model.get('date') ) #returns array of dates

    controller.setProperties
      content: days
      events:  events


App.CalendarWeekController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'calendarDay'
  events: null

  eventsChanged: ( ->

    #don't run if more records are scheduled to be loaded 
    #return if @get 'events.isUpdating'

    days     = @get 'content'
    children = @get '_subControllers'
    events   = @get 'events'
    user     = @get 'user'

    return unless days and children and events and user

    days.forEach (date) ->
      controller = children.findProperty 'content', date
      content = events.filter (event) ->
        (event.get('date') is date) and
        (event.get('user') is user)
      if content
        controller.set 'content', content

  ).observes('content', 'events.@each')
```

EDIT This is my current hack. Using the [unofficial Ember.debounce](https://gist.github.com/tchak/3529810)

```
  eventsChanged: ( ->

    days     = @get 'content'
    children = @get '_subControllers'
    events   = @get 'events'
    user     = @get 'user'

    return unless days and children and events and user

    days.forEach (date) ->
      controller = children.findProperty 'content', date
      content = events.filter (event) ->
        (event.get('date') is date) and
        (event.get('user') is user)
      if content
        controller.set 'content', content

    ).observes('content',  'didUpdate')

    notifyEventsChanged: Ember.debounce(
      @
      (_this) ->
        _this.notifyPropertyChange('didUpdate')
      200
      false
   ).observes('events.@each')
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have a good solution.

1. use `query` instead of `find`.
2. bind a listener on the `didLoad` attribute of the recordArray and toggle a attribute `isUpdating` on the controller
3. observe the controller `content` and `events` attributes separately.

---

```
App.CalendarWeekRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    login     = model.get 'login'
    week      = model.get 'week'
    events    = App.Event.all()
    newEvents = App.Event.query({login: login, week: week}, events)
    controller.setProperties
      isUpdating: true
      content: days
      events:  events
    newEvents.on 'didLoad', -> controller.set('isUpdating', false)

App.CalendarWeekController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'calendarDay'

  content: ( ->
    @update()
  ).observes('content')      

  eventsChanged: ( ->
    @update() unless @get 'isUpdating'
  ).observes('events.@each', 'isUpdating')

  update: ->
    days     = @get 'content'
    children = @get '_subControllers'
    events   = @get 'events'
    user     = @get 'user'
    days.forEach (date) ->
      controller = children.findProperty 'content', date
      content = events.filter (event) ->
        (event.get('date') is date) and
        (event.get('user') is user)
      controller.set 'content', content
```

Comment: Hi, Aaron, since you have done some work with dates in emberjs, do you mind looking at this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794581/emberjs-1-0-0-rc-6-using-enumerable-to-list-events-occurring-on-a-particular-dat . thanks

Comment: Can you please write this in JS and not coffee script

Answer (score 0):

You may want to observe `events.isLoaded` and test its value in the core of the function.

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug but isLoaded returns true almost immediately. My current hack is to defer the last execution of the function once the barrage of add records has ceased.

Comment: I have added my hack to my example. Let me know what you think. I think this (https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/735) is a relevant conversation.