# EmberJS, understanding DS Model life cycle

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to monitor the state changes on my DS Models.

I have found interesting flags in the documentation:

- [isLoading](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isLoading)
- [isReloading](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isReloading)
- [isSaving](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isSaving)

And they work properly in the templates, I can play with the `{{#if model.isLoading}}Is Loading{{/if}}`, for example.

But what is very disturbing is that the *observers* in these flags have a very random behavior. For example I have found that the *observer* over the flat `isSaving` doesn't work at all. But the *observer* over the flag `isReloading` works perfectly.

Here I have a full example of what I'm have tried until now. I have included this *Mixin* into my *Model*:

```
// app/models/mixins/loading-monitoring
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  isReloadingDidChange: Ember.observer('isReloading', function() {
    console.log('LOG: isReloadingDidChange', this.get('id'), this.get('isReloading'));
  }),

  isSavingDidChange: Ember.observer('isSaving', function() {
    console.log('LOG: isSavingDidChange', this.get('id'), this.get('isSaving'));
  }),

  isLoadingDidChange: Ember.observer('isLoading', function() {
    console.log('LOG: isLoadingDidChange', this.get('id'), this.get('isLoading'));
  }),

  isLoadedDidChange: Ember.observer('isLoaded', function() {
    console.log('LOG: isLoadedDidChange', this.get('id'), this.get('isLoaded'));
  }),

  onInit: Ember.on('init', function() {
    console.log('LOG: init', this.get('id'));
  }),

  onDidLoad: Ember.on('didLoad', function() {
    console.log('LOG: onDidLoad', this.get('id'));
  }),
});
```

And I try to invoke all these *observers* but only some ones are triggered:

```
> $E.toString()
  "<reports-dashboard-client-app@route:application::ember1553>"
> var report; $E.store.findRecord('report', 14).then(function(r) { report = r });
  Promise {_id: 438, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: Array[0]}
  LOG: init 14
  XHR finished loading: GET "http://myapi.com/reports/14".
  LOG: onDidLoad 14
> report.toString()
  "<reports-dashboard-client-app@model:report::ember1554:14>"
> report.get('title')
  "new title"
> report.set('title', 'title modified')
  "title modified"
> report.save()
  Class {__ember1453996199577: null, __ember_meta__: Meta}
  XHR finished loading: PUT "http://myapi.com/reports/14".send 
> report.reload()
  LOG: isReloadingDidChange 14 true
  Class {__ember1453996199577: null, __ember_meta__: Meta}
  XHR finished loading: GET "http://myapi.com/reports/14".send
  LOG: isReloadingDidChange 14 false
```

What am I missing?
What is the way to observe the state of the Model and react to changes: *loading*, *ready*?

Comment: Post in discuss: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/understanding-ds-model-life-cycle/9590?u=fguillen

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution, but you might try wrapping each `console.log` in `Ember.run.once()`. More info here https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/object-model/observers/

Comment: As far as I understand, observers do not fire on non-consumed properties. Do the LOGs fire when you render the model and use all the 'is*' flags in the template?

Edit: I am not sure if `model.get('isFoo')` counts as consummation.

Comment: Related links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346751/ember-data-observe-record-array-isloading-isupdating-hasupdated | https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4133 | http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-way-to-handle-isloading-isloaded-on-ember-data-model/4147

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 'isLoading', 'isLoaded' and 'isSaving' properties are all implemented as computed properties. In Ember, computed properties are lazy and do not compute their state until they are requested for the first time using `.get` or displayed in a template. So despite the fact that conceptually we as developers may know the value of `isLoading` is changing and will return a different value when `record.get('isLoading')` is called, as far as Ember is concerned the value of `isLoading` is undefined until some code explicitly asks Ember for that value and Ember takes the time to compute its state.

As a result, when you use `Ember.observer` to watch a computed property it will not be able to detect changes in the computed property until some other code has attempted to access the value of the computed property.

Observers also have a few other gotcha that you may want to be aware of. @stefanpenner has a good talk about their issues https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvZEddrClAQ and why they should be used sparingly.

In order to get your mixin to fire the observer events you will need to access those properties some where. The best place to do that looks to be in your `onInit` function. If you add `this.getProperties('isReloading', 'isSaving', 'isLoading', 'isLoaded');` to the `onInit` function then Ember will compute these values and the observers will correctly fire when the values of these properties are changed.

### The DS.Model Lifecycle

Under the hood, Ember Data maintains a state machine for reach record. This state machine is used to track the record's relationship with the server. At a high level these are the states an Ember Data record can be in:

- empty
- loading
- loaded

  - created

    - uncommitted
    - inFlight
  - saved
  - updated

    - uncommitted
    - inFlight
- deleted

  - saved
  - uncommitted
  - inFlight

`empty` Is the state where each record starts its life. Other then that fact `empty` is not very important.

`loading` Is the state a record is put in when Ember Data is requesting data from a server for the first time.

`loaded` Is the state a record is put in once Ember Data has received some info from the server about the record. It has a number of sub states that are used to track if there are changed made to the record locally that have not been saved to the server. If a record is created on the client side, it will be placed directly into the `loaded.created.uncommitted` state.

`deleted` is the sate for deleted records. The `deleted.saved` substate means the server has acknowledged a delete of this record. The `deleted.uncommitted` substate means there record has been deleted locally but `record.save()` has not been called.

A record's current state is exposed by the `currentState` property on a record. `isLoading`, `isLoaded` and `isSaving` are all aliases for `currentState.isLoading`, `currentState.isLoaded`, `currentState.isSaving` as each state in the state machine has predefined values for all of these properties.

I hope this explanation of the DS.Model's state machine helps.

As an additional thing to check out is the lifecycle events hooks that are exposed on `DS.Model` instances.
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#event_becameError

Comment: I really appreciate this @bmac, it is helping me a lot to understand about observers and computed properties.. can you add something about the main question I exposed?: _"What is the way to observe the state of the Model and react to changes: loading, ready?"_

Comment: I updated the response to how how you can get the observers to fire correctly.

Comment: Sadly this is not fixing the proble, the behaviour of the Observers with these Properties is very random as you can see in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GuKfBLvT). There are Observers that they are triggered even if the property has not change, or maybe it has changed in the mean time from the Observer was triggered and the console.log I do in the Observer itself.. :/

Comment: That's how Ember Data works. What's so random with that?

Comment: @DanielKmak you see I'm _observing_ changes in the `isLoading` property, but the property value is always `false` on each observer invocation when I `save()` the Model. Same behaviour with other properties that they look that the value has not changed but the _observer_ is still invoked. I think the property has indeed changed the state but when I'm into the _observer_ the property has modified the value so I can't actually know which is the value change that provoked the observer to be invoked.